# Why is there a WindowsError specifically but no other built in os specific exception?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

Python has built in exceptions for a generic [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError), and it has [`WindowsError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.WindowsError) which inherits from `OSError`. The docs explain that `WindowsError` is

> Raised when a Windows-specific error occurs or when the error number does not correspond to an errno value.

What's unclear is why there are Windows specific errors but not any specific to other OSes. Or at least, why other OS specific errors are not accounted for. Possibly this relates to *"when the error number does not correspond to an errno value"*, but that is similarly confusing. I thought `errno` was just an attribute of the exception raised that the exception returned. Why would there be an error number that doesn't correspond to an `errno` value?

Comment: In 3.3+ `WindowsError` is just an alias for `OSError`. Currently CPython  supports two major OS flavors, POSIX and Windows. POSIX uses [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html). The Windows C runtime also maps OS errors to `errno` values, but there are thousands of possible error codes in the Windows API (see [Windows Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231196)), so most Windows errors end up mapped to `EINVAL`. In that case the `winerror` attribute provides the real error code.

Comment: @eryksun That's very helpful, thank you! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python (and C, for that matter) is POSIX-centric.  That's not a bad thing per se, just something to be aware of.

So from Python's point of view, a POSIX error is just a normal error.  Nothing to see here.  But Windows errors don't map to POSIX errors on a 1:1 basis, so if an error occurs that can't be represented in POSIX terms an additional mechanism is needed.

If Python ran on (rolls dice) VMS, there might be a `VMSError` exception class too. :-)

Comment: There is a `VMSError`, but CPython hasn't supported VMS since 3.2, and all VMS code was removed in 3.4. For 2.7 there's a VMS port available at [vmspython.org](http://www.vmspython.org).

Comment: As I previously mentioned,  3.3+ no longer has `WindowsError` as a subclass of `OSError`. The constructor has been modified to include Windows error codes: `OSError(errno, strerror[, filename[, winerror[, filename2]]])`. Subclasses are now used to make it easier to handle specific exceptions. For example, `OSError(None, None, None, 5)` returns `PermissionError(13, None, None, 5)`. 5 is Windows `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. 13 is POSIX `EACCES` (as mapped by the C runtime).